# The response from API is not rendering first time in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am fetching response from API and i get array of objects from response and I am trying to render data from each objects. but in first render it is not rendering but when i enter any input or interchange between the components then it is visible. Please help me to resolve the issue.

```
const printList = () => {

        return(
            <div>
                {
                    array.map((data)=>
                        <div className="row" key={data.id} >
                            <div className="col-4" >{data.workshop.name}</div>
                            <div className="col-4" >{data.campaignId}</div>
                            <div className="col-4" >
                            <button >RESCHEDULE</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            </div>
        )
        
    }
```

the below is the api fetch

```
const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data.data);
        if(data.data!=undefined){
            for(let i=0;i<data.data.length;i++){
                arr.push(data.data[i]);
                setArray(arr);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please share your API call code details, please make the array a part of state, so that it can update components once data is updated in this array

Comment: How you call the API and assigned to the array.

Comment: I had added mine api fetch please help me i am stuck since 2 days